# Who invented or used very first the double lined symbols $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{N}$ etc

Tags: soft-question, notation, math-history

Who invented or used very first the double lined symbols $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{N}$ etc. to represent the real number system, rational number system, natural number system respectively?

Comment: The story I heard somewhere (Knuth's Texbook?) is that they are as so because forming boldface symbols on a chalkboard is difficult; hence "blackboard bold".

Answer (score 4):

A [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold) that seems to be relevant:

> $\ldots$ blackboard bold in fact originated from the attempt to write bold letters on blackboards in a way that clearly differentiated them from non-bold letters, and then made its way back in print form as a separate style from ordinary bold, possibly starting with the original 1965 edition of Gunning and Rossi's textbook on complex analysis.
>
> It is sometimes erroneously claimed that Bourbaki introduced the blackboard bold notation, but whereas individual members of the Bourbaki group may have popularized double-striking bold characters on the blackboard, their printed books use ordinary bold $\ldots$

Comment: It may be worth pointing out, however, that in the 1965 edition of Gunning/Rossi, the symbol for the real numbers looks different from $\mathbb{R}$. It is a serif-less R with thin strokes, and only the vertical line on the left doubled. Apparently, tastes changed since then.

Answer (score 3):

I have no references here, just stories my professor told us. As far as I know, the double lines were not double lines in the beginning, but rather boldened lines, so people wrote R with a slightly thicker vertical line to denote the real numbers.

The laziness of mathematitians and difficulty of writing a bolder line that students will recognise on a blackboard led to professors writing double lines instead of bold lines, and the practice stuck.